# How to display documents as grid of icons?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

What's the best way to let an iPad user browse a documents folder, with documents displayed as a grid of icons with captions? (Like the [events view in iPhoto](http://images.apple.com/ilife/iphoto/images/carousel-facebook-03_20101020.jpg), but with files and folders in place of events.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in control for this sort of UI. You could either use something like [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) (on GitHub) or build your own by subclassing UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

or you build it yourself like this:

```
-(void)createGrid
{
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<12; i++)
    {
        col = i % 2;
        row = i / 2;
        self.gridItem = [[ItemViewController alloc] init];
        [self.gridItem.view setTag:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.gridItem.view];
        [self.gridItem.view setFrame:CGRectMake(col*160, row*160, 160, 160)];
        [self addChildViewController:(UIViewController*) self.gridItem];
    }
}
```